# Syntax Error in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I think its been very simple question, but i'm stuck to it quite long time. I have a function but getting some brackets issue and unable to run the code. I'm not getting where the brackets should close.[image]

My code is,

```
-(void)Images{

    NSString *eachImagePath;
    if(_arrai.count == 0)
        return;

    eachImagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_arrai[0]];

    NSMutableDictionary *dictAddNewJobImages = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    dictAddNewJobImages[@"property_id"] = Propid;
    dictAddNewJobImages[@"name"] = _arrainame;

    NSString *strWebService = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My URL"];

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes=[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

    [manager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:600.0];

     [manager POST:strWebService parameters:dictAddNewJobImages constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData)
     {
         NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:eachImagePath];
         [formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath name:@"image" error:nil];
     } progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress)
     {
     } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask*  _Nonnull *task, id  _Nullable responseObject)
     {
         NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
         [_arrai removeObjectAtIndex:0];
         if(_arrai.count > 0)
             [self Images];
     } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask*  _Nullable task, NSError*  _Nonnull error) {
         NSLog(@"%@",error);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Add code as text not as image

Comment: The end of `[manage POST: is missing

Comment: yeah how to end it thats what i'm asking. @Jens

Comment: *How* with a `]`

Comment: Just hit `cmd`+`f` to search for `{` and for `}` to see whether the number matches. Same for `[` and `]`. Then you at least know what to look for.

Comment: When i place this ] than i got error with this success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask*  _Nonnull *task, id  _Nullable responseObject). @Jens

Answer (score 1):

you forget to close your block **}];**

use

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager GET:XXXXXX parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
 } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}]; --> add the close in failure
```

instead of

```
[manager GET:XXXXXX parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
 } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
```

**updated answer**

```
-(void)Images{

    NSString *eachImagePath;
    if(_arrai.count == 0)
        return;

    eachImagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_arrai[0]];

    NSMutableDictionary *dictAddNewJobImages = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    dictAddNewJobImages[@"property_id"] = Propid;
    dictAddNewJobImages[@"name"] = _arrainame;

    NSString *strWebService = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My URL"];

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes=[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

    [manager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:600.0];

     [manager POST:strWebService parameters:dictAddNewJobImages constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData)
     {
         NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:eachImagePath];
         [formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath name:@"image" error:nil];
     } progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress)
     {
     } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask*  _Nonnull *task, id  _Nullable responseObject)
     {
         NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
         [_arrai removeObjectAtIndex:0];
         if(_arrai.count > 0)
             [self Images];
     } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask*  _Nullable task, NSError*  _Nonnull error) {
         NSLog(@"%@",error);
      }]; -- > close your block here
   }
```

Comment: I want to run my code , just want to set my code i'm getting brackets error. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @HamzaImran - does not a problem , just append this `}];` in the place of `NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}` your code will work use `NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}]`

Comment: @HamzaImran - you start the block from here `[manager POST` but not closed the correct block close your block in here  `NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];`

Comment: I'm getting error on this success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask* _Nonnull *task, id _Nullable responseObject) as i write ur code.@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @HamzaImran - for example see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34938242/afnetworking-3-x-multipart-form-upload

Comment: @HamzaImran Just focus on last line of Anbu.Karthik's code and see, you have missed closing brass of block. Add `}]` at last line of web service call. It will resolve your issue.

Comment: @HamzaImran - your code is fine and correct, just close the block see my updated answer

Comment: Bro i'm getting error that Incompatible block pointer types sending void^(NSURLSessionDataTask*  _Nonnull *task, id  _Nullable responseObject) . In ur updated answer. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @HamzaImran - is this possible to attach your project , i will check

Comment: can u send me ur email id

Comment: @HamzaImran - are you sent the project

Comment: Where is ur email id? @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150970/discussion-between-anbu-karthik-and-hamza-imran).