# How to do multipart/form-data post request with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, multipartform-data, nsurlsession

```
 let Url = String(format: "http://url/ios.php")
    guard let serviceUrl = URL(string: Url) else { return }
    let parameterDictionary :[String:String] = ["Episodes" : "http://url/anime/07-ghost.html"]
    var request = URLRequest(url: serviceUrl)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: parameterDictionary)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response {
            print(response)
        }
        if let data = data {
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print(json)
            }catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        }.resume()
    }
```

I get error

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}
```

not sure if im sending data correctly, i think im setting httpbody incorectly

i even tried with json
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameterDictionary, options: []) else {
            return
        }

Comment: You can use AFNetworking - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34938242/afnetworking-3-x-multipart-form-upload

Comment: Why don't you try `Alamofire` 

Is there any particular reason

It is very easy to use
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Comment: figured it out
request.httpMethod = "POST"
    +        let postString = "Episodes=" + (animeModel?.link)!;
    Add a comment to this line
    +        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

Answer (score 4):

Swift 3,
Try this, Remove **responseHandler** parameter and any other if not use in your code

```
class func API_POST_FORM_DATA(param:[String : String], songData:Data?, fileName:String ,responseHandler : @escaping CompletionHandler)
{

    let API_URL = API_POST_ADD_SONG_TO_PLAYLIST
    print("API_URL : \(API_URL)")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: API_URL)!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let boundary = API_Calling.generateBoundaryString()

    //define the multipart request type

    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


    let body = NSMutableData()

    let fname = fileName
    let mimetype = "image/png"

    //define the data post parameter

    body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"test\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("hi\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

    body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

    body.append("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

    if let songRawData = songData
    {
        body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"song\"; filename=\"\(fname)\"\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append(songRawData)
    }
    body.append("\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

    body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

    for (key, value) in param
    {
        body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append("\(value)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    }

    request.httpBody = body as Data

    // return body as Data
    print("Fire....")
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        (
        data, response, error) in
        print("Complete")
        if error != nil
        {
            print("error upload : \(error)")
            responseHandler(nil)
            return
        }

        do
        {

            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]
            {
                responseHandler(json as NSDictionary?)
            }else
            {
                print("Invalid Json")
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            print("Some Error")
            responseHandler(nil)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

class func generateBoundaryString() -> String {
    return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
}
```