# Swift Url encoding to unicode characters

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsurl

I am trying to use following code for sending some information to the server.

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: GlobalVariable.globalIpAdresDispatch)!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; Charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
let postString = "saveBeyanname" + "&jp=" + myDraft + "&token=" + GlobalVariable.globalToken
request.httpBody = postString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlFragmentAllowed)?.data(using: .utf8)
```

myDraft variable comprises of a json string which includes ö,ç,i,ü letters. However when I send these information to server it is not accepting and they are converting ÅiÄÃ¼Ã§Ã¶ meaningless information. I have searched a lot and looked similar questions but still not working. How can I create my post string to send a server in a correct way?

Comment: try `CharacterSet.urlQuearyAllowed`.

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46628453/how-to-do-multipart-form-data-post-request-with-swift/48238993#48238993) may be it will help to make post request

Comment: What the differences between CharacterSet.urlFragmentAllowed and urlQueryAllowed. Now it worked thanks.

Comment: @AtalayAsa: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29806098/nscharacterset-urlhostallowedcharacterset-doesnt-replace-sign ?